# Using induction to prove an abstract problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

prove by induction that the order of a permutation $S_n$ is $n!$
This is what we have so far.
Proof:
Let $p(n)$ be a proposition.
$P(n): S_n = n!$
base case: $n=1$ then $(1) = 1! = 1$ 
Inductive hypothesis: we now assume $p(k)$ is true. We will now show that $p(k+1)$ must be true
$P(k) : S_k = k!$
$S_{k+1}$ 
right there i have problems i know i am going to use the induction hypothesis some how but my problems are the notation and the way i formulate the hypothesis. Any idea. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a valid proof: Fix the last element of an arbitrary permutation. You have $n+1$ possibilities to do so. From the induction hypothesis you know, that there are $n!$ possibilities for the other $n$ elements to permutate (since it doesn't matter how they are named). With this you get $(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$